# Deployment war file in weblogic 12c

Tags: weblogic12c

I tried to deploy a war file in weblogic 12c but i face the below problem:

[image]

By the way I deployed in tomcat without any error.

Last Lines in adminserver.log file is

```
####<Jan 30, 2018 12:55:12 PM AST> <Info> <Health> <DESKTOP-B1F3G3H> <AdminServer> <weblogic.GCMonitor> <<anonymous>> <> <> <1517306112127> <BEA-310002> <14% of the total memory in the server is free.> 
####<Jan 30, 2018 12:55:16 PM AST> <Error> <J2EE> <DESKTOP-B1F3G3H> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1517306116810> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
```

last Lines in domain log file is:

```
####<Jan 30, 2018 12:52:13 PM AST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <DESKTOP-B1F3G3H> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1517305933824> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
####<Jan 30, 2018 12:52:54 PM AST> <Warning> <Cluster> <DESKTOP-B1F3G3H> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1517305974807> <BEA-003121> <Unicast cluster may not function correctly as the listen address of server new_ManagedServer_2 is not specified.> 
####<Jan 30, 2018 12:55:16 PM AST> <Error> <J2EE> <DESKTOP-B1F3G3H> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <weblogic> <> <> <1517306116810> <BEA-160228> <AppMerge failed to merge your application. If you are running AppMerge on the command-line, merge again with the -verbose option for more details. See the error message(s) below.>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, provide adminserver log file.

Comment: I added the adminserver.log lines as you request

Comment: Your log file should also have details about this error. Please send lines next to the <Error>. Thx

Comment: unfortunately there is no more lines below, as the attached image

Comment: The image is for output logging. You should have more lines in WebLogic Server log files.

Comment: Really I don't know why there is no more lines in the log but as you see there is no more lines when it should !!!